# How to push & pop view controller with sliding animation effect?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uinavigationcontroller

I wants to push view controller along with below animation effect on Navigation view controller.

I tried this sample by using navigation controller delegate methods but not able to get that sliding effect.

https://gist.github.com/eoghain/7e9afdd43d1357fb8824126e0cbd491d

Please check below sample GIF for which type of animation exactly i needed.
[image]

Please take a look on navigation bar, i am just sliding left/right and it is doing push/pop of view controller.

Can anyone please help me on this how can i achieve this. Also please let me know it can be possible by using UIPageViewController or not ? If yes then how can i maintain top navigation bar same like GIF has.

Comment: Are you using a storyboard, or just code? Also, while you *can* navigation using a page view, it doesn't really have push/pop capabilities (i.e. it's own stack). But you *can* (at least in code) achieve what you want by (1) using a child VC that is a navigation VC along with 2) a page view at the bottom to "indicate" which VC is currently showing - all of which are part of a main VC.

Comment: Yes i am using Storyboard. Also can you please provides me any samples or just simple work through process so it will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful for you. You can try this example.

Create SecondViewController and set its identifier name. And load it with button click from your main ViewController.

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    @IBAction func gotoNextPage(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController")
        vc.view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        GlobalVariable.transitionViewFrom(from: self, to: vc, subtype: .fromRight)
    }
}

class GlobalVariable: NSObject {
    private static var sharedManager: GlobalVariable!
    public var allViewInstantController: [UIViewController]=[UIViewController]()
    public static let NUMBER_OF_VIEWCONTROLLER_OPEN_AT_A_TIME:Int = 5

    static func shared() -> GlobalVariable {
        if(sharedManager==nil){
            sharedManager=GlobalVariable()
        }
        return sharedManager
    }
    override private init() {
    }

    static func transitionViewFrom(from:UIViewController, to:UIViewController, subtype:CATransitionSubtype) -> Void {
        let timeDelay:Double=0.5
        GlobalVariable.checkPreviousView(_view:to)
        GlobalVariable.splashViewFrom(from: from, to:to, isAdd:true, subtype:subtype, timeDelay: timeDelay)
    }

    static func checkPreviousView(_view:UIViewController) -> Void {
        GlobalVariable.shared().allViewInstantController.append(_view)
        if(GlobalVariable.shared().allViewInstantController.count>GlobalVariable.NUMBER_OF_VIEWCONTROLLER_OPEN_AT_A_TIME){
            let myViewController = GlobalVariable.shared().allViewInstantController.first
            myViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
            GlobalVariable.shared().allViewInstantController.removeFirst()
        }
    }

    static func splashViewFrom(from:UIViewController, to:UIViewController, isAdd:Bool, subtype:CATransitionSubtype, timeDelay:Double) -> Void {
        do {
            let transition = CATransition()
            transition.duration = 0.25
            transition.isRemovedOnCompletion = true;
            transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
            transition.type = CATransitionType.push
            transition.subtype  = subtype
            from.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
            if(!isAdd){
                from.view.removeFromSuperview()
                if(GlobalVariable.shared().allViewInstantController.count>0){
                    GlobalVariable.shared().allViewInstantController.removeLast()
                }
            }else{
                from.view.addSubview(to.view)
            }
        }
    }

    static func dismissViewFrom(viewController:UIViewController, subtype:CATransitionSubtype) -> Void {
        let timeDelay=0.5
        GlobalVariable.splashViewFrom(from: viewController, to: UIViewController(), isAdd:false, subtype:subtype, timeDelay: timeDelay)
    }
}
```

SecondViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func gotoPreviousPage(_ sender: Any) {
        GlobalVariable.dismissViewFrom(viewController: self, subtype: CATransitionSubtype.fromLeft)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example code but this won't be work.

Comment: No there is no problem in code. But it won't able to provides desired output. Just imagine how page view controller works and they you will get an idea.

Comment: exactly, you can imagine how the page view controller works.

Comment: Yes but here as you mention i don't want to push second view controller by clicking any button from first view controller which is in root view controller. I wants to do it with swipe effect.